# Linechart using mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have used `achartengine` library to create `LineChart` by taking real time data. Now I want to replace this library with mpandroidchart library to get the same graph.

I want to replace the following code with mpandroidchart

```
TimeSeries dataset = new TimeSeries("temp");
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
```

With what header files and methods I can replace the above code to get the same Linechart?

Comment: It will be good if you follow [Mpchart Example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) to get whole understanding of each type of graph .

Answer (score 3):

You can implement by reffering below example of line chart using mpandroidcharts 3.0.4 :

```
    lineEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 3));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 3));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(6, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(7, 5));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(8, 7));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(9, 6));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(10, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(11, 5));

    lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Oil Price");
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2);
    lineDataSet.setColor(getColor("defaultBlue"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleColor(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));

    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);

    lineChart.getDescription().setText("Price in last 12 days");
    lineChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    lineChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    lineChart.setMarker(markerView(context));
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(lowerLimitLine(2,"Lower Limit",2,12,getColor("defaultOrange"),getColor("defaultOrange")));
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(upperLimitLine(5,"Upper Limit",2,12,getColor("defaultGreen"),getColor("defaultGreen")));
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    lineChart.animateY(1000);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1.0f);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(lineDataSet.getEntryCount());
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
```